**Stress Analysis and Displacement Calculation of a Hinged Structure Using Castigliano's Theorem**
The problem involves a structure consisting of two plates, CH and EN, and two tubes, ABC and LIH. There are hinges at the ends of CH, and at G there is a fillet with radius

r. Calculate the following: the maximum stress, the stress at point P, the allowable stress to achieve a safety factor (CS) of 2.5, and the displacement of point N using Castigliano's theorem (only symbolically).

We don't do homework, but do look at your attempted solutions to help find errors etc.

I did not know we accept questions in French!

@kamran that's not French.
